# I limit your movement, yet without me you'd not walk

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here's my third riddle today, and ever. This might be a bit more tricky than my last one, but I can't wait to see what you come up with.

> I limit your movement, yet without me you'd not walk.
>
> If you ever are without me, be careful of that lock!
>
> Being in my absence both will and won't be stressful,
>
> You might be embarassed if you ever prove me successful.
>
> Good luck faking me, many will try.
>
> Now riddle me this: What am I?

Hints will be added if you need them, good luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Guess

> Gravity?

I limit your movement, yet without me you'd not walk.

> You can't jump as high as on the moon, but it keeps you grounded.

If you ever are without me, be careful of that lock!

> Maybe you need gravity to lock things? Maybe air lock(From wolfram42)

Being in my absence both will and won't be stressful,

> It is weird being in micro-gravity but you are much lighter.

You might be embarassed if you ever prove me successful.

> You may trip because the gravity lets you fall(From Wolfram42)

Good luck faking me, many will try.

> There is research in simulating gravity at least in scifi(from wolfram42)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but you beat me to it. For the lock: rot13(guvax nveybpx) For success: rot13(Snyyvat qbja vf tenivgl'f fhpprff). For faking: Gurer vf erfrnepu va fvzhyngvat tenivgl ng yrnfg va fpvsv

Comment: Cool thanks, I will add that @wolfram42

Comment: 100% right gentlemen. @QuantumTwinkie Eventually I will stump you, just you wait

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it fits well, but are you

> muscles / joints

I limit your movement, yet without me you'd not walk.

> muscles/joints can only move in the direction that they are made to go, yet without them we'd be a piles of bones and nerves that can't do anything.

If you ever are without me, be careful of that lock!

> missing/overused muscles and joints can cause a lock-up in your body. Remember those muscle cramps? charlie horse? yeah.

Being in my absence both will and won't be stressful,

> without muscles it is hard to stand but if you use a wheelchair you don't have to have the stress of walking (like in *The Secret Garden*), you can't lift anything with sore muscles, you can't move properly without correct joints, etc.

You might be embarrassed if you ever prove me successful.

> hmm... this is where I get stuck.

Good luck faking me, many will try.

> muscle implants, to get that *hot bod!*

Comment: You're thinking of *The Secret Garden*, BTW.

Comment: Interesting take, but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the intended answer, but it's not a bad fit. Here goes:

> I limit your movement, yet without me you'd not walk.
>
> !Time = distance/speed, so more time on a journey lowers speed. But likewise, there is no movement without time existing.
>
> If you ever are without me, be careful of that lock!
>
> !When you're in a hurry (no time), you may either forget to lock up, or be delayed further by a locked door. You may even find you were late, and your destination has already locked up for the night!
>
> Being in my absence both will and won't be stressful,
>
> !If you are out of time, it's normally very stressful. But if your time is up (you are dead), there is no stress.
>
> You might be embarassed if you ever prove me successful.
>
> !In a race against time, you only win if you are on time. If time wins, you are late. Embarrassing, no?
>
> Good luck faking me, many will try.
>
> !People try to look younger and lie about their age all the time. Few can actually manage to look much younger.